# What are good things to inherit when making a cms that is extendable and/or pluggable?

Tags: design-patterns, content-management-system

I can see where creating a database connection class is helpful, extend that class, use it wherever, change one place, submit queries with it, and so on.  But, other than a database connection class, db settings, path setting, what would be the sort of thing that you would want to inherit from the top level class?

and why do CMS builders make it so that you have to inherit from that top class?  I guess anyone can hack a page and put raw php in it and make it work but not in the fashion it was designed to do....but other than that the designer "makes" you inherit that class.  Is there a way to build in an Interface that check to see if you did indeed inherit like you were supposed to?

I'm trying to figure out what exactly makes it worthwhile to inherit anything.  Is there more to extending or plugging in modules and what that really means?

Answer (score 1):

The two reasons I usually see for OO inheritance particular to CMS systems have to do with persistence and representing hierarchy.

Persistence comes into play if you're dealing with a system that has its own sort of ORM. In this way you can easily CRUD and query entities without the need for new tables. It also more easily opens up opportunities for defining relationships between different types of entities, such that a folder class might have a getContents method that returns say an array of other entities.

Hierarchy comes into play by have a base type that requires specifying a parent entity. Most CMS systems rely heavily on representing content in some sort of parent child fashion or modeling a folder structure directly. So, this type of quality in a base class ensures adherence.

As far as interfaces are concerned, really depends on language you're using. If you have a weakly typed system, then so long as your objects implement the correct methods you need not implement an interface. If you are actually extending a concrete top level, you'd probably find digging around its innards algorithms for the aforementioned persistence and parsing through hierarchy therein.